# How to remove the method's input parameter class < T >, each call will be convenient

Tags: java, generics

```
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONArray;
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.samples.ar.entity.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Demo<T> {
    private T t;

    public <T> List<T> getOnet(List<Map<String, Object>> list, Class<T> tClass) {
        //Null pointer exception in this way
        //But this way is convenient, how to realize
        //return (List<T>) JSONArray.parseArray(JSON.toJSONString(list), t.getClass());
        return JSONArray.parseArray(JSON.toJSONString(list), tClass);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();
        Class<? extends User> aClass = user.getClass();
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("id", i);
            list.add(map);
        }
        List<User> users = new Demo<User>().getOnet(list, User.class);
        System.out.println(users);
    }
}
```

Environment：Java 8，IntelliJ IDEA

If there is no class `<T>` input parameter of the method, each call will be convenient. Similar to the implementation of MyBatis plus.

I was worried that the picture would not be displayed, so I wrote this method out

```
com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.mapper.BaseMapper

T selectById(Serializable id);
```

[Mybatis-plus BaseMapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrh3Z.png)

Answer (score 1):

> If there is no class < T > input parameter of the method, each call will be convenient

The generics couldn't be used then. Remember you want to serialize JSON into an object, so you need to pass a type of the object through `Class<T> tClass`. However, the whole thing can be simplified:

- Remove the generic type from `Demo<T>` resulting in `Demo`.
- Remove the unused type `private T t;`.
- Define the method `getOnet` with an explicit generic type:

  ```
  public <T> List<T> getOnet(List<Map<String, Object>> list, Class<T> tClass) {
      return JSONArray.parseArray(JSON.toJSONString(list), tClass);
  }
  ```

The usage of this method becomes straightforward as long as the generic type becomes *inferred*.

```
List<User> users = new Main().getOnet(list, User.class);
```